# MySQL server frequently lost but application works perfectly

Tags: php, laravel, queue, task, scheduler

Environment is `Godaddy`, shared hosting using `Linux`, `Mysql`, `php 7.2, laravel 5.7`.

I have not touched framework code. I simply used `Laravel` documentation to run artisan commands and log information.

I created a `cronjob` that runs every 5 min to run scheduler for email jobs 
that periodically sends mails based on registration, birthdays and other activities and backing-up DB at 4 times a day. I get the errors in my log file described below:

> production.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away (SQL: select * from `jobs` where `queue` = default and ((`reserved_at` is null and `available_at` <= timestamp) or (`reserved_at` <= timestamp)) order by `id` asc limit 1 for update). Timestamps are different but query is same.
>
> production.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) {"exception":"[object] (PDOException(code: 2002):SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'
>
> production.ERROR: Call to a member function beginTransaction() on null 
>   {"exception":"[object] Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception \FatalThrowableError (code: 0):

None of the scheduled tasks were either aborted or not executed for any error. All these scheduled tasks get executed perfectly. Ex: When I request an email send, it gets posted to same jobs table, and the same entries are vanished in a flash and I get the mail delivered at the destination. Strangely, I get this error frequently in between, when no activity or interaction with the application is done (meaning none is interacting with the application). I do not find any issue with the query as I have executed the same query in `phpMyAdmin`, in my local console or in `MySQL workbench`. This is the default framework query.

```
protected $commands = [
    //
    Commands\SendBirthdayEmail::class,
    Commands\SendReminderEmail::class,
    Commands\ManageLogs::class,
    Commands\BackupDb::class,
];

/**
 * Define the application's command schedule.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
 * @return void
 */
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{

   $schedule->command('manage:logfiles')->weekly()->sundays()->at('01:15');
   $schedule->command('backup:stdb')->dailyAt('01:20');
   $schedule->command('backup:stdb')->dailyAt('05:20');

   $schedule->command('email:birthday')->dailyAt('05:55');
   $schedule->command('email:reminder')->dailyAt('06:00');

   $schedule->command('backup:stdb')->dailyAt('13:45');
   $schedule->command('backup:stdb')->dailyAt('19:20');
   $schedule->command('backup:stdb')->dailyAt('21:20');
   $schedule->command('queue:work --tries=3')->everyFiveMinutes();
}
```

Even after these entries (supposedly with lost connection state), the next task gets executed perfectly as desired.

I have searched all over but could not find an issue with jobs table as well as the reason for these log entries. Always the same jobs table is shown as the problematic query.

Comment: I am of the opinion that it has nothing to do with timeouts or size of queries or packet size as the table is empty (no jobs pending).  I have also examined the MySQL PROCESSLIST only two/three present

Comment: I believe the server memory is exhausting in a cron process or maybe due to some other reason and mysql can not run its own process. For example see [this](http://www.prowebdev.us/2012/05/amazon-ec2-linux-micro-swap-space.html) even if yorus is shared hosting on godaddy just as a proof of reference.

Comment: Thank you and you could be right but when I have examined the server memory it never crossed the 68-70% of allocation. Secondly, an application running (no interaction with it) should not be consuming too much resources except for cronjob which runs every 5 minues. I have not seen any spikes in CPU usage or memory when these errors were detected. I will still look into this suggestion.

Comment: I have also checked the default swap space allotted to us which is 8GB, out of which ~ 1 GB occupied and 6.8 GB free.The issue beyond me!

Comment: What’s there in MySQL error logs  for the period when it failed ?

Comment: I am not sure whether I am answering correct. I have only examined the status tab under which all red marked numbers were collected to improve performance. In that there are slow queries number. I am wondering looking at some of the numbers, whether it is only for my part of MySQL (it is shared hosting) or it reflects the whole bunch of users together as some of the variable like kill process etc., were never used my package.

Comment: I thinking in CPanel or WHM you would be able to find logs. Generally it’s inside /var/log/MySQL/error.log

Comment: Solved: Looks like. The culprit seems to be the last schedule command queue:work --tries=3.  After I have commented out, the error did not appear in the last 10 hours. Everything else has worked just fine.